# Как избежать XSS и прочих уязвимостей при хранении HTML в бд? (SQL)

Tags: php, html, sql, база-данных, xss

У меня есть редактор текста в комментариях и панели администратора (страница добавления статей и прочего) с разными режимами по типу жирный текст/курсив/подчеркнутый и т.д. На других форумах говорят, что использовать подготовленные запросы - достаточно. Я использую PDO. Но что делать при выводе HTML-контента в DOM? (Контент хранится в БД для того, чтобы сохранить span-элементы с соответствующими каждому режиму печати стилями)

Можно с помощью регулярки находить текст между тегами  и отдельно его экранировать. Хотелось бы услышать ваши предположения и советы

Comment: *"что делать при выводе HTML-контента "* ---  использовать преобразование в спец символы. Например в php есть 
 функция `htmlentities`

Comment: Алексей, действие этого метода аналогично htmlspecialchars? Но ведь при его использовании все будет отображаться текстом? Или вы предлагаете применить его только к определенным тегам?

Comment: Отображается всё текстом... Только всякие символы заменены на спец. последовательности. Это видно непосредственно в исходном коде станицы, а не на экране монитора